# Magento configurable product is out of stock in front end for Multiple store website

Tags: php, magento

I have added some configurable product and in backend inventory setting is "in stock" but in front end that product is showing as a out of stock. i have cleared cache and re-indexing is also done but still it is showing as a "out of stock". Please help why it is happening like this and how to resolve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using a multi store website please make sure that all the associated simple products are associated with the same store as the configurable product itself.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Hina,for concept of configurable product , `frontend configurable produc`t stock is `depending on it child products stock(qty and is_stock)`.If `any of  one child product`(means simple product )of configurable

```
stock is in stock and  configurable product attribute is_in_stock is in stock then frontend  stock status is in stock
```

More reference:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/creating-a-configurable-product

http://www.sitepoint.com/adding-configurable-products-magento-ecommerce-site/

Comment: ! Thanks for your response. i have already added every simple product of configurable product in "in-stock" but it is showing out of stock only